# Nikon D810 - how to see focus points?

Tags: nikon, dslr, autofocus

In the viewfinder inside D810, I'd like to see the focus points. While tinkering with AF types, I think I did something and I don't see the live little squares I used to see in the past. Is there any way to enable this again?

Comment: Turn back on whatever you turned off? WHat does your D810 *User Manual* say about activating AF points in the viewfinder?

Comment: Michael, if the manual was easy to search and understand, I'd have done that instead of asking here. The "custom settings" stuff is very hard to understand. Why is this a custom setting, this should be a function of the camera.

Comment: Custom settings *are* one way to control functions of the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per page 309 and 310 of your [user manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/Uslma00vmWju01F4NIw08vXsPQ61/D810FM_DL(En)01.pdf), check custom settings a5 and a6.

Comment: While this answer may be correct, could you re-count or summarise what those pages say? I am sure the asker - and dozens of people down the track finding this answer - will not be helped to resolve their issue if they don't have the manual to hand :/

Comment: I've linked directly to the user manual PDF in my answer...

Comment: Thank you. I found that setting now, and it works. Much appreciated.